# Path generator application for android

Tags: java, android, vector, path

I'm trying to draw custom shapes for an android application that I am developing an I am doing so using paths.

```
public Path makeFloorPath(){
    Path p = new Path();
    p.moveTo(50, 300);
    p.lineTo(100, 250);
    p.quadTo(200, 250, 250, 200);
    p.lineTo(250, 250);
    p.lineTo(300, 300);
    p.close();
    return p;
}
```

However a lot of the time it seems like a guessing game.
Is there a free path generator app out there which allows you to visually draw paths?

The best I have found is this http://codecanyon.net/item/path-generator/full_screen_preview/337072
The problem is this program has limitations as you can not edit points but you can generate java paths.

Comment: you can use canvas and bitmap with paint class as the alternative option to draw custom shapes .what you want exactly , elaborate it more .